# Why I got this object params array attached to my object result in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this object named **@forum_posts** which populate all my **forum posts**. And when I render this in the view, I got the results along with the array of it's params like shown below:

[image]

Here is how i defined @forum_posts in the forum_posts.rb controller:

`@forum_posts = ForumPost.all`

And even if I defined it directly in the view by using `ForumPost.all each ..` , I still got this weird stuff happening.

**routes.rb**

```
# app/config/routes.rb
resources :forums do
  resources :forum_posts, module: :forums
end
```

**forums_controller.rb**

```
# app/controllers/forums_controller.rb
class ForumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_forum, except: [:index, :new, :create]

  def index
    @forum_posts = ForumPost.all
  end

  def show
    @forum_post = ForumPost.new
  end

  def new
    @forum = Forum.new
    @forum.forum_posts.new
  end

  def create
    @forum = current_user.forums.new forum_params
    @forum.forum_posts.first.user_id = current_user.id

    if @forum.save
      redirect_to @forum
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private

    def set_forum
      @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    end

    def forum_params
      params.require(:forum).permit(:subject, forum_posts_attributes: [:body])
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb view**

```
<!-- app/views/forums/index.html.erb -->
<%= @forum_posts.all.each do |forum_post| %>
  <%= forum_post.id %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @ManojMenon nope i didn't inspect elements anywhere as you can see in the codes above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `=` in the first line like this:

```
<% @forum_posts.all.each do |forum_post| %>
 <%= forum_post.id %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Note that if you have `=` you are rendering.

```
<% %>  ----> Executes the ruby code within the brackets.

<%= %> ----> Prints something into erb file.
```

Comment: ahh silly me...Thanks!